# Unable to change prototype cell UIButton image without reload UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a table view  to display sound files along with a play button in each prototype cell. I am trying to play the sound file incorporated with the selected cell when user tap on the play button.

In the code I am changing the `UIImage` of the `UIButton` once user click on it. And while finished playing it will reset to default button image. But it is unable to change the `UIImage`  of the previous selection if user click on next cell button on the time of playing the current track.

Please suggest me what is going wrong in my code.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *dirPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dirPath error:nil];

    // UITableViewPlayer *cellPlayer;
    _cellPlayer = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    _cellPlayer.btnPlay.tag = indexPath.row;
    _cellPlayer.btnPlay.titleLabel.hidden = YES;

    [_cellPlayer.btnPlay addTarget:self action:@selector(playCurrenTrack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    _cellPlayer.pView.tag = indexPath.row;


    _cellPlayer.songTitle.text = [fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return _cellPlayer;

}



-(void)playCurrenTrack : (id) sender{


    UIButton *clicked = (UIButton *) sender;

    NSInteger rowNumber = clicked.tag;

    // reset the default button
    for (int i = 0; i < DirctoryList.count; i++) {

        UITableViewPlayer *cellPlayer = [self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];

        [cellPlayer.btnPlay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

    NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNumber inSection:0];


    UITableViewPlayer *currentView = (UITableViewPlayer *)[myTableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];

    if(rowNumber == playerIndex && [player isPlaying]){
        [currentView.btnPlay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [player pause];
        return;
    }else if(rowNumber == playerIndex && isPlayerBusy){
         [currentView.btnPlay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [player play];
        return;

    }

    [player stop];


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *fileListAct = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];


    NSString *FinalFile= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileListAct[rowNumber]];
    NSString *strippedContent = [FinalFile stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *FinalPath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:strippedContent];


    NSURL * soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:FinalPath];


    NSError *error;
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
              initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL
              error:&error];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: NO error: nil];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
              [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {

        player.delegate = self;
        [player prepareToPlay];
        // set the index for checking current playing track
        playerIndex = clicked.tag;
        isPlayerBusy = TRUE;
        [player play];

        [currentView.btnPlay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        /*
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(UpdateProgressBar:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:`. Also you may want to keep a record of the index number of the current playing item, rather than loop through all every time. BTW. don't know whether `DirctoryList` has spelling error.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am using the UITableViewPlayer *cellPlayer as weak reference  so is it any problem. I will rectify the DirectoryList. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code might help someone. It is working for me

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    playerIndex = -1;
    prevSelection = nil;

}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString

    *dirPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dirPath error:nil];

    // UITableViewPlayer *cellPlayer;
    cellPlayer = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cellPlayer.btnPlay.tag = indexPath.row;
    cellPlayer.btnPlay.titleLabel.hidden = YES;


    [cellPlayer.btnPlay addTarget:self action:@selector(playCurrenTrack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cellPlayer.pView.tag = indexPath.row;


    cellPlayer.songTitle.text = [fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cellPlayer;

}

-(void)playCurrenTrack : (id) sender{


    UIButton *clicked = (UIButton *) sender;

    NSInteger rowNumber = clicked.tag;


    NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNumber inSection:0];


    UITableViewPlayer *currentView = (UITableViewPlayer *)[myTableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];

    if(rowNumber == playerIndex){

        if([player isPlaying]){

            [currentView.btnPlay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [player pause];
        }else{
            [currentView.btnPlay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [player play];

        }


    }else{

        if([player isPlaying]){
            [player stop];
        }


        if (prevSelection != nil) {
            UITableViewPlayer *prevView = (UITableViewPlayer *)[myTableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:prevSelection];
            // make your priviousView player stop code here using priviousView & reload that indexpath
            [prevView.btnPlay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[prevSelection] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

        }

        prevSelection = nil;

        [currentView.btnPlay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    }

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *fileListAct = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];


    NSString *FinalFile= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileListAct[rowNumber]];
    NSString *strippedContent = [FinalFile stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *FinalPath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:strippedContent];


    NSURL * soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:FinalPath];


    NSError *error;
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
              initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL
              error:&error];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: NO error: nil];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
              [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {

        player.delegate = self;
        [player prepareToPlay];
        // set the index for checking current playing track
        playerIndex = clicked.tag;
        //set prevCell
        prevSelection = myIP;
        isPlayerBusy = TRUE;
        [player play];


        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(UpdateProgressBar:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do 2 things:

1. First inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set `selectedImage` for `_cellPlayer.btnPlay` like:

   ```
   [_cellPlayer.btnPlay setImage:@"selectedImage" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
   ```
2. Then in `playCurrenTrack` set it selected.

   ```
   [_cellPlayer.btnPlay setSelected:YES];
   ```

Don't forget to readjust it in case when you play other list's item. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to store previous  cell indexpath. take one NSIndexPath object globel for that class like  `NSIndexPath *priviousSelected;`

and modified your playCurrenTrack as below and write your stop image logic for `UITableViewPlayer *priviousView`  instead of comments  // make your priviousView player stop

```
-(void)playCurrenTrack : (id) sender{


    UIButton *clicked = (UIButton *) sender;

    NSInteger rowNumber = clicked.tag;

    // reset the default button
    for (int i = 0; i < DirctoryList.count; i++) {

        UITableViewPlayer *cellPlayer = [self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];

        [cellPlayer.btnPlay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

    NSIndexPath *myIP = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNumber inSection:0];


    UITableViewPlayer *currentView = (UITableViewPlayer *)[myTableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:myIP];

    if(rowNumber == playerIndex && [player isPlaying]){
        [currentView.btnPlay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [player pause];
        priviousSelected = nil;
        return;
    }else if(rowNumber == playerIndex && isPlayerBusy){
        [currentView.btnPlay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        if (priviousSelected != nil) {
            UITableViewPlayer *priviousView = (UITableViewPlayer *)[myTableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:priviousSelected];
            // make your priviousView player stop code here using priviousView & reload that indexpath

        }
        priviousSelected = myIP;
        [player play];
        return;

    }

    [player stop];


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *fileListAct = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];


    NSString *FinalFile= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileListAct[rowNumber]];
    NSString *strippedContent = [FinalFile stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *FinalPath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:strippedContent];


    NSURL * soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:FinalPath];


    NSError *error;
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
              initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL
              error:&error];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: NO error: nil];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
              [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {

        player.delegate = self;
        [player prepareToPlay];
        // set the index for checking current playing track
        playerIndex = clicked.tag;
        isPlayerBusy = TRUE;
        [player play];

        [currentView.btnPlay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        /*
         [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(UpdateProgressBar:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jay thank you for your solution. It was totally out of my mind. I have change the code little bit. Now it absolutely working fine with the previous Selected IndexPath. I have posted the working code below in answer

Comment: if you find it correct then accept my answer and votes up